# Nan issue with pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a data file with a header. The data file is attached and I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('TestData.out', sep=' ', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

The issue is that I have 20 columns in my data file, while I am getting 32 columns in the variable data. How can I resolve this issue. I am very new to Python and I am learning.

[Data_File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R7bYC1xFfuXMz9Wp-2RaEVpvGsHO7Wb6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Access is currently denied on the file

Comment: Oh! sorry, let me look at that

Comment: Should work now, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Text File has two spaces together, in from  of any value that does not have a minus sign.  if `sep=' '`, pandas sees this as two delimiters with nothing (`Nan`) inbetween.

This will fix it:

```
data = pd.read_csv('TestData.out', sep='\s+', skiprows=1, header=None)
```

In this case the `sep` is interpreted as a regex, which looks for "one of more spaces" as the delimiter, and reurns Columns 0 though 19.

Answer (score 0):

Your data file has inconsistent space delimitation. So, you just have to skip the subsequent space after the delimiter. This simple code works:

```
data= pd.read_csv('TestData.out',sep=' ',skiprows=1,skipinitialspace=True)
```

Comment: This eats up one row, it only outputs 99 rows out of 100

Comment: Yes, your file has non-header data as the first row. So, you have to skip parsing it using skiprows=1.